# Is this written correctly?

Tags: translation, phrases

I've come across this phrase かっこいポーズのリクストにこたえてくれました and I simply can't understand it, something about a cool pose perhaps? I don't know if it's written correctly either. I've tried translating it word by word but even so, it doesn't make much sense. Sorry for such a stupid question lol, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「かっこいポーズの**リクスト**にこたえてくれました 。」

would be a perfect sentence if you changed 「リクスト」 to 「リクエスト」 and 「かっこい」 to 「かっこいい」.

> 「かっこいいポーズのリク**エ**ストにこたえてくれました 。」
>
> = "***(Someone) responded to my/our request for a cool-looking pose***."

「～～**に**[応]{こた}える」 = "to respond ***to*** ~~"  ← The ***only*** correct particle is 「に」 here.

Comment: 「かっこい」←「い」が足りないのはいいんですかね・・

Comment: 「かっこいい」と言われ慣れてる割には気づきませんでした。訂正します。

Comment: :D ------------

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure but I think instead of FOR, it's more like WITH... "(Someone) responded to my/our request WITH a cool-looking pose."

Comment: @Alice28 "responded to my request WITH a cool-looking pose" would be 「かっこいいポーズ**で**リクエストにこたえてくれました 。」

Comment: If we are faithful to the given Japanese quote, "恰好いいポーズのリクストに応えてくれました, it could be "He responded to my request for hiｍ to strike a pose.